# Why is my application window going off screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, height

I have a C# WPF application I am building. Currently when I run it on my machine in a 1024 x 768 screen resolution environment it all fits. However when I send it to a co-worker he has a 1280 x 800 resolution and the application window runs off the bottom edge of his screen so he cant re-size it or see all of the content in the window. I am running Windows 7 and he is running Windows XP if that makes any difference. In addition in my XAML code I have the 'Height' and 'MinHeight' attributes both set to 700, so I would think it shouldn't start out taller than 700.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the DPI setting in Windows?

Comment: Do you have content in your window that is changing the size?  Does he have a larger font size or DPI setting in Windows?

Comment: When the application loads, does your code increase the height? If so, then even dring a load it can go beyond 700 px.

Comment: There is nothing that changes height in my code. How do you check DPI settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF specifies sizes and locations in *inches*, not in pixels.  The unit is 1/96 inch.  So your Height setting of 700 specifies a window that's 700 / 96 = 7.292 inch high.

In all likelihood, your co-worker might be wearing glasses and has increased the dots-per-inch setting of his video adapter from 96 to 120 dpi (125% on the ruler) to make it easier to read text.  Which makes your window 7.292 * 120 = 875 pixels high.  That doesn't fit the 800 pixels that the monitor can display.

You'll need to make your window smaller.  No more than 800 / 120 * 96 = 640.  Less to allow room for the task bar if it is on the bottom.  Or preferably support resizable window layouts.

Comment: Turns out that was the exact problem: my DPI was 96 and his was magnified to 120